# Entity Framework and relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I'm using EF 5 rc on VS 2012 RC and got some issues. Pretty sure it's got to do with my knowledge in databases and EF than the version numbers of the software I use :)

So, I have 3 classes. User, Role and Right.

**User class**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; internal set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; internal set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    // More properties 
}
```

**Right Class**

```
public class Right
{
    public virtual int RightId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Role Class**

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

```
 class MyContext : DbContext
 {
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Right> Rights { get; set; }
 }
```

Now, I want to add *roles* to a *user*, and *rights* to a *role*. But I also want to make sure it's possible to add the same *Right* can be added to different *roles*.

```
 var role1 = new Role()
{
     Description = "role1"
};

var role2 = new Role()
{
    Description = "role2"
};

var right = new Right()
{
    Description = "right"
};

context.Rights.Add(right);
context.Roles.Add(role1);
context.Roles.Add(role2);

role1.Rights = new List<Right>();
role2.Rights = new List<Right>();
role1.Rights.Add(right);
role2.Rights.Add(right);

 /**** ERROR ****/
context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting

> InvalidOperationException: Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Role_Rights_Source' of the relationship 'Role_Rights' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Also, I don't feel right about creating a new list like

```
 role1.Rights = new List<Right>();
 role2.Rights = new List<Right>();
```

What's the recommended way to do this ? Rights property is null. So I can't add anything to it without newing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the convention used by EF to infer the relation. It thinks that the relation is one-to-many but you want many-to-many (role can have multiple rights and the right can be used in multiple roles).

There are two options to solve this:

**Option 1: Create navigation property in Right:**

```
public class Right
{
    public virtual int RightId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now EF convention will detect the collection on both sides of the relation and correctly use many-to-many multiplicity instead of one-to-many

**Option 2: Use Fluent-API to tell EF that you want many-to-many relation:**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Right> Rights { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                    .HasMany(r => r.Rights)
                    .WithMany();
    }
}
```

Now EF knows that the `Right` can be assigned to multiple roles even through the `Right` doesn't have navigation property to `Role`.

If the `Role` can be assigned to multiple users you will have to use many-to-many relation as well

Comment: Wow, you just solved the issue keeping me awake for the last 3 days. (shows how great I am with EF.) I assume that, with **option 1** if I add a role to a right, EF will also map that the Role will have the right ?

Comment: Yes - EF will internally create junction table in database to work with many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 1):

Ladislav's Answer should work well for the error.

On your issue of being uncomfortable with using:

```
role1.Rights = new List<Right>();
```

You should just initialize the these properties to new Lists in the constructor, then it will be done for all instances of Role:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; }

public Role ()
{
this.Rights =  new List<Right>();    
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that... That'll save me a lot of null checks... :)

Comment: If you need a lot of this don't after you have generated a database with the model. Just work backwards by recreating the model from the database and EF will add these automatically with some Fluent mappings too http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/entity-framework-existing-sql-server-database-code-second/